# kill all processes spawned by parent with `ssh -x -n` on other hosts

Tags: ssh, kill, background-process

Hi
A software named G09 works in parallel using Linda. It spawns its parallel child processes on other nodes (hosts) as

`/usr/bin/ssh -x compute-0-127.local -n /usr/local/g09l/g09/linda-exe/l1002.exel ...other_opts...`

However, when the master node kills this process, the corresponding child process on other node, namely compute-0-127 does not die but keeps running in background. Right now, I manually go to each node which has these orphaned Linda processes and kill them with `kill`. Is there any way to kill such child processes?

Look at pastebin 1 for PSTREE before killing the process and at pastebin 2 for PSTREE after parent is killed
pastebin1 - http://pastebin.com/yNXFR28V
pastebin2 - http:// pastebin.com/ApwXrueh
-not enough reputation points for hyperlinking second pastebin, sorry !(
Update to Answer1
Thanks Martin for explaining. I tried following

```
killme() { kill 0 ; } ; #Make calls to prepare for running G09 ; 
g09 < "$g09inp" > "$g09out" &
trap killme 'TERM'
wait
```

but when Torque/Maui (which handles job execution) kills the job(this script) as `qdel $jobid` the processes started by G09 as `ssh -x $host -n` still run in the background. What am I doing wrong here ? (Normal termination is not a problem as G09 itself stops those processes.) Following is `pstree` before `qdel`

```
bash
|-461.norma.iitb. /opt/torque/mom_priv/jobs/461.norma.iitb.ac.in.SC
|   `-g09
|       `-l1002.exe 1048576000Pd-C-C-addn-H-MO6-fwd-opt.chk
|           `-cLindaLauncher/tmp/viaExecDataN6
|               |-l1002.exel 1048576000Pd-C-C-addn-H-MO6-fwd-opt.ch
|               |   |-{l1002.exel}
|               |   |-{l1002.exel}
|               |   |-{l1002.exel}
|               |   |-{l1002.exel}
|               |   |-{l1002.exel}
|               |   |-{l1002.exel}
|               |   |-{l1002.exel}
|               |   `-{l1002.exel}
|               |-ssh -x compute-0-149.local -n ...
|               |-ssh -x compute-0-147.local -n ...
|               |-ssh -x compute-0-146.local -n ...
|               |-{cLindaLauncher}
|               `-{cLindaLauncher}
`-pbs_demux
```

and after `qdel` it still shows

```
461.norma.iitb. /opt/torque/mom_priv/jobs/461.norma.iitb.ac.in.SC
`-ssh -x -n compute-0-149 rm\040-rf\040/state/partition1/trirag09/461

l1002.exel 1048576000Pd-C-C-addn-H-MO6-fwd-opt.ch
|-{l1002.exel}
|-{l1002.exel}
|-{l1002.exel}
|-{l1002.exel}
|-{l1002.exel}
|-{l1002.exel}
|-{l1002.exel}
`-{l1002.exel}

ssh -x compute-0-149.local -n /usr/local/g09l/g09/linda-exe/l1002.exel

ssh -x compute-0-147.local -n /usr/local/g09l/g09/linda-exe/l1002.exel

ssh -x compute-0-146.local -n /usr/local/g09l/g09/linda-exe/l1002.exel
```

What am I doing wrong here ? is the `trap killme 'TERM'` wrong ?

Comment: Did you write these processes?

Comment: no, they are created by G09 binaries (G09 is software for Quantum Chemistry Simulations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following approach:

- create a script/application that wraps this g09 binary that you are starting, and start that wrapper instead
- in the script, wait for the HUP signal to arrive (which should be received when the ssh connection is closed)
- in processing the HUP signal, send a signal to your process group (i.e. PID 0) that kills all processes in the group.

Sending a KILL signal to the process group is really easy: `kill -9 0`. Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
./b.sh 1 &
./b.sh 2 &
sleep 10
kill -9 0
```

where b.sh is

```
#!/bin/sh
while /bin/true
do
  echo $1
  sleep 1
done
```

You can have as many child processes as you want (directly or indirectly); they will all get the signal - as long as they don't detach themselves from the process group.

Comment: Thanks this is very much constructive and useful [now I only need to decipher it in codes, errm not an expert in bash scripting :( ] Can you please elaborate ? We use Torque-Maui (its a cluster/resource manager) which sends HUP signal to the script which calls G09 binary. So I already have wrapper script which calls G09 (the binary which starts the `ssh -x -n` processes)

Comment: See my edit of how to kill a process group. You don't have to use SIGKILL, of course.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I have edited my question to reflect my attempts to implement your solution, however, it did not work, can you please look into the updated question?

Comment: I'm confused. The script you wrote: how is that related to the pstree output? In particular, what is 461.norma.iitb? If that's the script, there is no surprise it didn't execute the kill: it still keeps running, so apparently, it didn't receive SIGTERM (which, in turn, might not be surprising as you said SIGHUP will be sent, not SIGTERM).

Comment: Further comment: put some `touch /tmp/foo ` action into the trap function, to see whether it gets executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using `ssh -N` (similar to `ssh -n`), and `kill -9 0` does not work for me if I run it inside a script that initiates the ssh call. I find that `kill jobs -p` does terminate the ssh process, which is not very elegant, but I am using that currently.